# Advice on plotting large amount of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm working on a very cheap seismometer mainly for educational purposes and some research. I would like to show every few hours the seismic signal of one of the channels as the image I have attached, using `matplotlib`.

The problem is that every second I get 100 datapoints and while plotting this data on a raspberry pi, usually hangs and stop working.

The way I plot the data for each 4 hours subplot is reading again all the data and plotting only between the limits of the subplot, but I find this not efficient and probably the cause of the raspberry hanging.

I've been thinking for days how I could do this to avoid using a lot of memory for each subplot, but I can't find an answer as I'm a geologist and programming is a big issue for me.

Does anybody have a better idea for doing this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import os.path
import datetime
import sys
import numpy
import pytz
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import ftplib
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice
from time import sleep
from matplotlib.pyplot import specgram
from scipy.signal import medfilt
import csv
archivo='sismo1545436800'

def subirftp(archivosubir):
    session = ftplib.FTP('---', 's---   ', '----')
    file = open(archivosubir+'.png', 'rb')  # file to send
    session.storbinary('STOR '+ archivosubir +'.png', file)  # send the file
    dirlist = session.retrlines('LIST')
    file.close()  # close file and FTP
    session.quit()

font = {'family': 'serif',
            'color': 'darkred',
            'weight': 'normal',
            'size': 16,
            }

fu = open('Z:/nchazarra/sismografos/' + str(archivo) + '.txt')
nr_of_lines = sum(1 for line in fu)
fu.close()
f = open('Z:/nchazarra/sismografos/' + str(archivo) + '.txt')

print(nr_of_lines)
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
#row_count = sum(1 for row in csv_f)
#print(row_count)
tiempo = []
valora = []
valores = []
tiempor = []
i=0
final=0
empiezo=time.time()

for row in islice(csv_f,0,nr_of_lines-1):
        # print (row[0])
        if i == 0:
            inicio = double(row[0])
            valor = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(row[0]),tz=pytz.utc)
            tiempo.append(valor)
            i = i + 1
        else:
            valor = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(row[0]),tz=pytz.utc)
            #print(valor)
            tiempo.append(valor)
            # print(row)

        try:
            valora.append(int(row[1]))
            # print(row[0])
        except IndexError:
            valora.append(0)
        except ValueError:
            valora.append(0)

valores = valora
tiempor = tiempo
mediana = np.mean(valores)
minimo = np.amin(valores)
maximo = np.amax(valores)
std = np.std(valores)
for index in range(len(valores)):
        valores[index] = float(((valores[index] - minimo) / (maximo - minimo))-1)

mediananueva = float(np.median(valores))
for index in range(len(valores)):
    valores[index] = float(valores[index] - mediananueva)

valores2=np.asarray(valores)
tiempo2=np.asarray(tiempo)

#Franja de 0 a 4
franja1=plt.subplot(611)
franja1.axis([datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22,00,00), datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22,3,59,59),-0.05,0.05])
franja1.plot(tiempo2, valores2, lw=0.2,color='red')
#Franja de 4 a 8
franja2=plt.subplot(612)
franja2.axis([datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22,4,00), datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22,8,00),-0.05,0.05])
franja2.plot(tiempo2, valores2, lw=0.2,color='green')

#Franja de 8 a 12
franja3=plt.subplot(613)
franja3.axis([datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22,8,00), datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22,12,00),-0.05,0.05])
franja3.plot(tiempo2, valores2, lw=0.2,color='blue')
#Franja de 12 a 16

franja4=plt.subplot(614)
franja4.axis([datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22,12,00), datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22,16,00),-0.05,0.05])
franja4.plot(tiempo2, valores2, lw=0.2,color='red')

#franja de 16 a 20

franja5=plt.subplot(615)
franja5.axis([datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22,16,00), datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22,20,00),-0.05,0.05])
franja5.plot(tiempo2, valores2, lw=0.2,color='green')

#Franja de 20 a 24
franja6=plt.subplot(616)
franja6.axis([datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22,20,00), datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22,23,59,59),-0.05,0.05])
franja6.plot(tiempo2, valores2, lw=0.2,color='blue')

franja1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
franja2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
franja3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
franja4.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
franja5.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
franja6.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

acabo=time.time()
cuantotardo=acabo-empiezo
print('Madre mía, he tardado en hacer esto '+str(cuantotardo)+' segundos')

savefig(archivo + ".png", dpi=300)
subirftp(archivo)
plt.show()
```

[image: Seismic Drum]

Comment: What part of your code is using a lot of memory? What do you consider "a lot of memory"?

Comment: @martineau, the plotting part uses a lot of memory because for each subplot, I have to read all the array again, and the files are around 300Mb each.

Comment: 300MB isn't really that much memory nowadays, although reading it from a file might take, relatively speaking, a long while—so it sound like you want to improve performance.  That could be done by figuring out how to incrementally get the data. Do you have any control over the production of the csv file being read (the `'z:/nchazarra/sismografos/' + str(archivo) + '.txt'` file)? If you do, then changing the way the data is being stored would be one way to avoid reading in a bunch of it that's not needed each time.

Comment: Yes, I control the data capture. The format is a csv file as follows, although I'm only interested in timestamp and plotting the zvalue for the seismic drum:
timestamp, xvalue, yvalue, zvalue

Comment: Good, because that gives you a least two options. One would be to generate a separate file for each increment. The file names of each file would need to be unique—perhaps by having a timestamp in them—and you would need to periodically delete old ones (perhaps after adding the data in them to some separate summary file if you want to keep it). The other option would be to make each row of a single large file the same length, that way, you could easily `seek()` to the "last 100 points" section of the file and only read that portion.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to plot every data point? You could consider plotting every 100 or so. As long as the frequency of your signal isn't too high, I think it could work. Something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(10000) / 10000 * 2 * np.pi
Y = np.sin(X) + np.random.normal(size=10000) / 10

plt.plot(X[::100], Y[::100])
```

[image]

versus all points:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I need to show all the data because if not, it looks distorted. I've been plotting it every 2, 5 and 10 data points and the seismic signal looks really weird :(

Comment: If you're making an application, the first "high-level" graph should show every n-th point, but a "zoom-in" feature would allow for viewing a dense plot over a smaller range which should be fine memory-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a fair bit of memory by sub-setting the arrays before you plot them:

```
import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

n_times = 24 * 60 * 60 * 100
times = [
    datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22,00,00) +
    datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=10 * x) for x in range(n_times)]
tiempo2 = np.array(times)
valores2 = np.random.normal(size=n_times)

#Franja de 0 a 4
franja1=plt.subplot(611)
index = np.logical_and(tiempo2 >= datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 0, 0),
                       tiempo2 < datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 4, 0, 0))
franja1.plot(tiempo2[index], valores2[index], lw=0.2,color='red')

#Franja de 4 a 8
franja2=plt.subplot(612)
index = np.logical_and(tiempo2 >= datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 4, 0),
                       tiempo2 < datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 8, 0, 0))
franja2.plot(tiempo2[index], valores2[index], lw=0.2,color='green')

#Franja de 8 a 12
franja3=plt.subplot(613)
index = np.logical_and(tiempo2 >= datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 8, 0),
                       tiempo2 < datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 12, 0, 0))
franja3.plot(tiempo2[index], valores2[index], lw=0.2,color='blue')
#Franja de 12 a 16

franja4=plt.subplot(614)
index = np.logical_and(tiempo2 >= datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 12, 0),
                       tiempo2 < datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 16, 0, 0))
franja4.plot(tiempo2[index], valores2[index], lw=0.2,color='red')

#franja de 16 a 20

franja5=plt.subplot(615)
index = np.logical_and(tiempo2 >= datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 16, 0),
                       tiempo2 < datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 20, 0, 0))
franja5.plot(tiempo2[index], valores2[index], lw=0.2,color='green')

#Franja de 20 a 24
franja6=plt.subplot(616)
index = np.logical_and(tiempo2 >= datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 20, 0),
                       tiempo2 < datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 23, 0, 0, 0))
franja6.plot(tiempo2[index], valores2[index], lw=0.2,color='blue')

franja1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
franja2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
franja3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
franja4.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
franja5.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
franja6.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

plt.show()
```

[image]